# Wildfly Deployment with Oracle Datasource

Tags: oracle, deployment, datasource, wildfly

I am trying to deploy Wildfly 10 for a JSF-EJB project.

I have my ***oracle.jdeveloper.db.connection.jar*** defined in my Library in eclipse(4.4.0) and placed ***ojdbc6.jar*** in the following path  **C:\wildfly\wildfly-10.0.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base\com\oracle\main** with ***module.xml***.

I have successfully tested the datasource from [localhost:9990/console](http://localhost:9990/console)

Below is my ***web.xml*** reference:

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>DB Connection</description>
    <res-ref-name>java:/OracleDS</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>  
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>  
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
```

I am using the following Datasource in the ***standalone.xml***

```
        <datasources>
            <datasource jndi-name="java:/OracleDS" pool-name="OracleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe</connection-url>
                <driver>oracle</driver>
                <pool>
                    <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
                    <max-pool-size>5</max-pool-size>
                    <prefill>true</prefill>
                </pool>
                <security>
                    <user-name>Example</user-name>
                    <password>XXX</password>
                </security>
            </datasource>
            <drivers>
                <driver name="oracle" module="com.oracle">
                    <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>
        </datasources>
```

I am using the following line in ***module.xml***:

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="com.oracle">

    <resources>
        <resource-root path="ojdbc6.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/> 
        <module name="javax.servlet.api" optional="true"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

During deployment I receive the 2 following errors. Both are related with the Datasource:

> 17:20:19,404 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread
>   1-1) MSC000001: Failed to start service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."test11_R_Copy.war".INSTALL:
>   org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."test11_R_Copy.war".INSTALL: WFLYSRV0153: Failed
>   to process phase INSTALL of deployment "test11_R_Copy.war"    at
>   org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:154)
>     at
>   org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
>     at
>   org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ***Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WFLYEE0047: Incompatible
>   conflicting binding at java:/OracleDS source: lookup
>   (java:comp/DefaultDataSource)***  at
>   org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.addJndiBinding(ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.java:238)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.deploy(ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.java:107)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:147)
>     ... 5 more

The following ERROR also refers to the Datasource.

> 17:20:19,419 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation]
>   (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy")
>   failed - address: ([("deployment" => "test11_R_Copy.war")]) - failure
>   description: {
>       "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"test11_R_Copy.war\".INSTALL" =>
>   "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
>   jboss.deployment.unit.\"test11_R_Copy.war\".INSTALL: WFLYSRV0153:
>   Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"test11_R_Copy.war\"
>   ***>     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WFLYEE0047: Incompatible conflicting binding at java:/OracleDS source: lookup
>   (java:comp/DefaultDataSource)"},***
>       "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
>           "jboss.deployment.unit.\"test11_R_Copy.war\".batch.environment is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"test11_R_Copy.war\".beanmanager]",
>           "jboss.deployment.unit.\"test11_R_Copy.war\".weld.weldClassIntrospector
>   is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"test11_R_Copy.war\".beanmanager]"

I am not using the **persistence.xml**.

Where am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not a naming expert, but maybe try removing the reference from your web.xml. It should be seen already by the deployment by the way it's configured.

Comment: @James thank you. This is where the issue was I changed the xml tag it worked. I will publish the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It solved by replacing `<resource-ref>` by `<resource-env-ref>`

Answer (score 3):

Comment the `resource-ref` element in `web.xml` and everything works just fine.

`<!--
<resource-ref>
    <description>DB Connection</description>
    <res-ref-name>java:/OracleDS</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>

    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>

    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>

-->`